# How do I open an Angular project in Visual Studio that was created with the CLI?

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I created an Angular project from the command line.  If I want to edit this in Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017 is there a way to do so such that Visual Studio recognizes it as a project and understands the structure?

Comment: I wish when people down vote your question they leave an explanation why so we can better formulate questions or post them somewhere else if appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 go to `File >> Open >> Folder` and select the root folder for your Angular project.